# Oracle SQL - Multiplewhere conditions based on each other from the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a single table `ledrow` Which has 4 columns.

I want to only select rows where they have (per `vnum` and `comp`) rows that are in both sets of logic.

**English Explanation**

---

So for example out of all the data below, explaining the rows in the expected output is as follows:

For `comp` 99 we have results as all of the `vacc` numbers fall into either of the sets of logic:

The `vacc` is either `BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567'` OR the `vacc` is `BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999'`

However for example `comp` 77 rows aren't output because even though:

```
comp vtype  vnum    vacc
77   F      1369    3400
77   F      1369    3402
```

Comes under the second part of the logic the rest of the rows don't fall under any:

```
comp vtype  vnum    vacc
77   F      1369    1510
77   F      1369    2620
77   F      1369    2620
77   F      1369    2620
77   F      1369    1650
```

This is because to be part of the output I want all rows per comp MUST fall in either parts of the logic per comp.

---

I have tried the following code but cannot get my expected output.

Current Code:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT comp, vtype, vnum, vacc
FROM ledrow
WHERE 
((comp = '55' AND vacc BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567') AND (comp = '55' AND (vacc = '3019' OR vacc = '5222')))
OR
((comp = '66' AND vacc BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567') AND (comp = '66' AND (vacc  = '3013' OR (vacc BETWEEN '6910' AND '6973'))))
OR
((comp NOT IN ('55', '66') AND vacc BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567') AND (comp NOT IN ('55', '66') AND (vacc BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999')))) outputled
WHERE outputled.vtype = 'F'
```

Expected Output:

```
comp vtype  vnum    vacc
99   F      1369    1564
99   F      1369    2610
99   F      1369    2610
99   F      1369    3601
99   F      1369    3600
```

Full Table (`SELECT * FROM ledrow`):

**ledrow**

```
comp vtype  vnum    vacc
77   F      1369    1510
77   F      1369    2620
77   F      1369    2620
77   F      1369    2620
77   F      1369    3400
77   F      1369    3402
77   F      1369    1650
99   F      1369    1564
99   F      1369    2610
99   F      1369    2610
99   F      1369    3601
99   F      1369    3600
99   I      1369    2450
99   I      1369    2440
99   I      1369    2640
99   J      1369    5430
99   J      1369    2450
99   J      1369    5430
99   J      1369    2455
99   J      1369    5410
99   J      1369    2455
99   J      1369    5410
22   F      1369    2620
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    2495
22   F      1369    1510
22   F      1369    2620
22   F      1369    2620
22   F      1369    2620
22   F      1369    2620
22   F      1369    2620
22   F      1369    2620
22   F      1369    2620
22   F      1369    2620
22   F      1369    2620
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    2495
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    2495
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    2495
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    2495
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    2495
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    2495
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    2495
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    2495
22   F      1369    3500
22   F      1369    2495
22   I      1369    2450
22   I      1369    2440
22   I      1369    2640
22   J      1369    5520
22   J      1369    5520
22   J      1369    2455
22   J      1369    2450
```

**Edit**

So for each `vnum` and `comp` it needs to satisfy both of the two conditions in the WHERE clause.

So for `comp` `99` which has to satisfy both the conditions:

```
((comp NOT IN ('55', '66') AND vacc BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567') AND (comp NOT IN ('55', '66') AND (vacc BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999'))))
```

Comment: 'I want to only select rows where they have (per vnum and comp) rows that are in both sets of logic' What does that even mean?

Comment: Please try to explain your logic, because some of the conditions doesn't make sense.

Comment: @wvdz added a bit more explanation in question

Comment: @sagi added a bit more explanation in question

Comment: @Matt you should be able to formulate your requirement in plain English. 'needs to satisfy both where clauses'. You use the AND operator for that, but I guess you know that. So it's still very poorly formulated.

Comment: @wvdz Not quite, the rows for a particular comp need to satisfy both requirements, not only one side. look at the expected output, only the comp `99` does this as its rows that satisfy both parts of comp `99`'s where clasue: `((comp NOT IN ('55', '66') AND vacc BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567') AND (comp NOT IN ('55', '66') AND (vacc BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999'))))`

Comment: @Matt I just don't understand why you need SQL code to formulate your requirement. Forget about the code, and just formulate your requirement in plain English. If you can't do that, you probably don't really know what you want.

Comment: @wvdz i have now multiple times in the comments, but i will add the to the questions

Comment: @wvdz i have added a FULL English explanation with examples.

Comment: @Matt okay I think I now understand your requirement. If I now understand correctly: All rows with a comp id for which there doesn't exist a row with that comp id for which vacc id is not between 3000 and 3099, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood what you were trying to do, then this should work :

```
    WHERE comp = '55' AND (vacc between '1544' and '1567' or vacc in('3019','5222')) OR
          (comp = '66' AND (vacc between '1544' and '1567' or vacc between '6910' AND '6973' or vacc = '3013')) OR
          (comp not IN('55','66') and (vacc BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567' or vacc BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999'))
```

You specified each of the first conditions twice, which is not necessary as they are correct to both of the next conditions.

```
(comp not IN('55','66') AND Cond1) AND/OR (comp not IN('55','66') AND Cond2)
```

Equals to:

```
comp not IN('55','66') AND (Cond1 AND/OR Cond2)
```

**EDIT:** You can try something like this:

```
SELECT tt.* FROM (
    SELECT t.comp FROM (
        SELECT comp,
               CASE WHEN comp = '55' AND vacc BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567' THEN 1
                    WHEN comp = '55' AND vacc in('3019','5222') THEN 2
                    WHEN comp = '66' AND vacc BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567' THEN 3
                    WHEN comp = '66' AND (vacc  = '3013' OR (vacc BETWEEN '6910' AND '6973')) THEN 4
                    WHEN comp NOT IN ('55', '66') AND vacc BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567' THEN 5
                    WHEN comp NOT IN ('55', '66') AND (vacc BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999') THEN 6
                    ELSE 7
                END as ind_col
        FROM ledrow
        WHERE vtype = 'F') t
    GROUP BY t.comp 
    HAVING (MAX(t.ind_col) = 2 and min(t.ind_col) = 1) OR
           (MAX(t.ind_col) = 4 and min(t.ind_col) = 3) OR
           (MAX(t.ind_col) = 6 and min(t.ind_col) = 5)) s
INNER JOIN ledrow tt
 ON(s.comp = tt.comp)
WHERE tt.vtype = 'F'
```

This will basically give an indication to each row, first condition is `1,2` corresponding to the part of this condition the satisfied , second one is `3,4` and third is `5,6` . Then you check that each group only has 1+2 or 3+4 or 5+6 with the `HAVING` clause with `MAX()` and `MIN()` which will assure that this `comp` satisfy **both** conditions.

This solution works only for rows that satisfy both conditions, not only one of them. If only one of them is enough, that change the having clause to this:

```
    HAVING (MAX(t.ind_col) = 2 and min(t.ind_col) = 1) OR
           (MAX(t.ind_col) = 4 and min(t.ind_col) = 3) OR
           (MAX(t.ind_col) = 6 and min(t.ind_col) = 5) OR
           (MAX(t.ind_col) = min(t.ind_col) and min(t.ind_col) IN(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Comment: Thats bringing back too many lines: for example it returns:
`77   F      1369    3400` & `77   F      1369    3402` but comp '77' and vnum '1369' dont have rows that satisfy the second part of the WHERE clause `vacc BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567'`

Comment: @Matt But they answer the second part of it `between '3000' and '3999'` , they can't be equal to both. Why do you have this second condition if you don't want this rows then ?

Comment: because i only want rows where both parts are satisfied per comp and vnum and if it only matches the first part then dont show any.

Comment: so comp 99 satisfy both parts of `((comp NOT IN ('55', '66') AND vacc BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567') AND (comp NOT IN ('55', '66') AND (vacc BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999'))))` BUT comp `77` does not.

Comment: Thats not what im saying, I know a row cant satisfy two conditions, im saying PER comp its rows should fall into either of the conditions BUT all the rows must all fall into either of them or NONE of them should be shown.  Hope that makes more sense

Comment: @Matt I think I understood what you are saying, try my update, this should return all comps that answers only both conditions . You can do what ever you want with this list, if you want the rest of the columns, join my query to the table.

Comment: thanks for sticking with this one. Can the new query be amended to show vtype, vnum & vacc please.

Comment: Excellent, the query is still running so I will let you know as soon as it has finished!

Comment: Yea, its far from being efficient :) You should add the proper indexes to make this run faster or maybe test it on smaller data sets @Matt

Answer (score 2):

May be I have understood what you want :)

We make every special conditions per comp (group by comp) like a bit in a byte (1,2,4,8) and then add them. Than we choose only the combination what we want. 
(1+2=3, 1+4=5, 1+8=9)

```
SELECT *
  FROM ledrow
 WHERE vtype = 'F'
   AND comp IN 
      (SELECT comp
         FROM (  SELECT comp,
                        MAX (CASE WHEN (vacc BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
                        + MAX (CASE WHEN (comp = '55' AND vacc IN ('3019', '5222')) THEN 2 ELSE 0 END)
                        + MAX (CASE WHEN (comp = '66' AND (vacc = '3013' OR vacc BETWEEN '6910' AND '6973')) THEN 4 ELSE 0 END)
                        + MAX (CASE WHEN (comp NOT IN ('55', '66') AND vacc BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999') THEN 8 ELSE 0 END)
                           x
                   FROM ledrow
                  WHERE vtype = 'F'
               GROUP BY comp)
        WHERE bitand(x,3) = 3 OR bitand(x,5) = 5 OR bitand(x,9) = 9)
```

Another modification with analytic function [MAX() OVER ()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions098.htm#SQLRF00666), but the same logic

```
SELECT comp, vtype, vnum, vacc
  FROM (SELECT x.*,
               MAX (CASE WHEN (vacc BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY comp) c1,
               MAX (CASE WHEN (comp = '55' AND vacc IN ('3019', '5222')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY comp) c2,
               MAX (CASE WHEN (comp = '66' AND (vacc = '3013' OR vacc BETWEEN '6910' AND '6973')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY comp) c4,
               MAX (CASE WHEN (comp NOT IN ('55', '66') AND vacc BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY comp) c8
          FROM testtest2 x
         WHERE vtype = 'F')
 WHERE (c1 = 1 AND c2 = 1)
    OR (c1 = 1 AND c4 = 1)
    OR (c1 = 1 AND c8 = 1)
```

Comment: `1)` Its the same as my answer with no explanation provided. `2)` multiple equals with `OR` can be converted into `IN()` .

Comment: 1) You forgot 'F' 2) yes

Comment: I didn't forget anything, I just adjusted his conditions.

Comment: @Matt. Ok Matt tell what should happen with the row 77 F 1369 3400. the vacc is between 3000 and 3999 comp is not 55 or 66. vtype is F.  vacc cannot be between  3000 and 3999 and in  the same time between 1544 and 1567

Comment: I know that im saying for each row all rows must fall into EITHER one other wise show none of them