# Oracle SQL - Using the results from two queries as the WHERE condition in another

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two queries.

Query 1:

```
SELECT g.ccc, g.nnn, g.ttt, g.aaa
FROM table1 g
WHERE g.aaa BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999'
AND g.ccc NOT IN('05','06') 
AND g.nnn = '1369'
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT g.ccc, g.nnn, g.ttt, g.aaa
FROM table1 g
WHERE g.aaa BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567'
AND g.ccc NOT IN('05','06') 
AND g.nnn = '1369'
```

Query 1 Output:

```
ccc nnn     ttt aaa
07  1369    F   3400
07  1369    F   3402
19  1369    F   3601
19  1369    F   3600
20  1369    F   3500
20  1369    F   3500
20  1369    F   3500
20  1369    F   3500
20  1369    F   3500
20  1369    F   3500
20  1369    F   3500
20  1369    F   3500
20  1369    F   3500
20  1369    F   3500
20  1369    F   3500
```

Query 2 Output:

```
ccc nnn     ttt aaa
19  1369    F   1564
```

What I want to get is using the results of these two tables to get an output where when a ccc has results in both queries all of the returned data from both queries are output, if a ccc has results in only one query, or in none, then none of its results are output.

Expected Output:

```
ccc nnn     ttt aaa
19  1369    F   3601
19  1369    F   3600
19  1369    F   1564
```

Comment: Matt what is the difference between this and your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789356/oracle-sql-multiplewhere-conditions-based-on-each-other-from-the-same-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this, seem complicated, might be a bit optimized

```
SELECT g.ccc, g.nnn, g.ttt, g.aaa
  FROM table1 g,
(
SELECT distinct g.ccc
FROM table1 g
WHERE (g.aaa BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567'
      or g.aaa BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999')
AND g.ccc NOT IN('05','06') 
AND g.nnn = '1369'
) t.ccc
WHERE g.aaa BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567'
AND g.ccc=t.ccc
AND g.nnn = '1369'
union
SELECT g.ccc, g.nnn, g.ttt, g.aaa
FROM table1 g,
(
SELECT distinct g.ccc
FROM table1 g
WHERE (g.aaa BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567'
      or g.aaa BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999')
AND g.ccc NOT IN('05','06') 
AND g.nnn = '1369'
) t.ccc
WHERE g.aaa BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999'
AND g.ccc=t.ccc
AND g.nnn = '1369'
```

Comment: not exactly what i want but it allowed me to develop my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
WITH query1 AS (
   SELECT g.ccc, g.nnn, g.ttt, g.aaa
   FROM table1 g
   WHERE g.aaa BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999'
   AND g.ccc NOT IN('05','06') 
   AND g.nnn = '1369'
),
query2 AS (
   SELECT g.ccc, g.nnn, g.ttt, g.aaa
   FROM table1 g
   WHERE g.aaa BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567'
   AND g.ccc NOT IN('05','06') 
   AND g.nnn = '1369'
)
SELECT * FROM query1
WHERE ccc IN ( SELECT ccc FROM query2 )
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM query2
WHERE ccc IN ( SELECT ccc FROM query1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the analytic functions [MAX() OVER ()](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions098.htm#SQLRF00666), with partition by ccc

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT x.*,
               MAX (CASE WHEN (g.aaa BETWEEN '3000' AND '3999' AND g.ccc NOT IN ('05', '06') AND g.nnn = '1369') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ccc) c1,
               MAX (CASE WHEN (g.aaa BETWEEN '1544' AND '1567' AND g.ccc NOT IN ('05', '06') AND g.nnn = '1369') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ccc) c2
          FROM table1 g)
 WHERE c1 = 1 AND c2 = 1
```